# A brute man speaks very “insert word here”

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word to describe the way a brute man speaks.  One example would be officiously, but I think there is a better word to describe this.  It’s on the tip of my tongue.

A sample sentence would be:

> A brute man speaks very "insert word here".

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please see the guidance on making [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) as your post is not very descriptive. For example, what is a "brute man" and why would *officiously* be inadequate to your needs? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: He probably speaks *brutishly*

Comment: You got two answers, each quite different, but each applicable to the word _brute_.  I went with definition 1.1 of the adjective form, a merely physical man (a la Andre the Giant, despite his penchant for rhyme), whereas @lbf went more with definition 1.2, fundamental and unpleasant coming up with _crudely_, perhaps with more of a foul-mouthed gangster in mind.  **And this is exactly why more context and a better sample sentence is required for this sort of question.**

Answer (score 1):

**crudely**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/crudely) adv

> in a crude or unrefined manner
>
> in a crude and unskilled manner

As in:

A brute man speaks very **crudely**.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *brute man*, I can't help but think of Andre the Giant's part in *The Princess Bride* wherein he says to someone "I'm on the brute squad" and the response is "You *are* the brute squad."  The *brute squad* is supposed to be a group of strong, perhaps violent men organized to roust everyone out of a forest in anticipation of the royal wedding.  The definition of *brute* at the Oxford Living Dictionaries supports this:

> ***[brute](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brute)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A savagely violent person or animal.
>
>    *‘he was a cold-blooded brute’*
>
>    1.1 *informal* A cruel or insensitive person.
>
>    *‘what an unfeeling little brute you are’*
>
>    1.2 Something awkward, difficult, or unpleasant.
>
>    *‘a great brute of a machine’*
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. *[attributive]* Characterized by an absence of reasoning or intelligence.
>
>    *‘a brute struggle for social superiority’*
>
>    1.1 Merely physical.
>
>    *‘we achieve little by brute force’*
>
>    1.2 Fundamental, inescapable, and unpleasant.
>
>    *‘the brute necessities of basic subsistence’*

So, based on all this, the word I would suggest is ***forcefully***, meaning *with a lot of force*.  Again, from the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[forcefully](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forcefully)***
>
> **ADVERB**
>
> 1. In a strong and assertive manner; vigorously.
>
>    *‘he argued forcefully against reform’*
>    *‘the government need to act forcefully on this issue’*
>
>    1.1 Using considerable physical strength or violence.
>
>    *‘he forcefully shoved her back into the wall’*
>    *‘exhale forcefully through your nose’*

So, for your example, you would have:

> *A brute man speaks very **forcefully**.*

Comment: You don't have to be a brute to speak forcefully.

Comment: @Robusto -- True, but that doesn't mean a brute wouldn't speak forcefully.  I mean, I suppose a brute could speak softly (and carry a big stick?) but I think that's less likely.

Comment: Not sure why this warrants a downvote -- while even a quiet grandmother type can speak forcefully, in my mind a brute is a big guy, very physical (def. 1.1) and thus _forcefully_ seems entirely appropriate.  Think of the scene in _The Princess Bride_ where Inigo and Fezzik are trying to get through a crowd and Fezzik bellows, quite ***forcefully***, "everybody move!" and they do.  Which is why I took the time to provide an explanation of where I was coming from.